# I'm trying to use curl with php but getting this error:Could not resolve host: Bearer

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to make a request using curl with php, but I'm getting the following error. Could I be using curl wrong?
I generate $jwt on top lines

```
exec("curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer $jwt' \"https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/refund/lookup/1234\"")

Could not resolve host: Bearer
```

This is how I can use it on this site [apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests)

Comment: Why are you running it from the shell instead of using the built-in functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use curl like this

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.storekit.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/{original_transaction_id}');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');


$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Authorization: Bearer '. $jwt;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I see the result of this process in the terminal?

Comment: Yes, just add some code to display the `$result`. I edited the answer,check it